# Truclient object identification

Tags: truclient

We have a page where with dozens of rows listing tasks that we have created. We have named the tasks unique so we can use a loop in TruClient to scroll down the page until we find that text. Our page has us then clicking on the link to the left of that text.All links and text are placed with in div elemwnts. With TruClient how we can do.

The latest link is not always at the top or bottom of the screen, and we can't grab the link details before we get to this page (functionality has us creating this case, and the case ID isn't presented to the page before this)

The closest functionality that I can see would be use a Click on link took, and use the "Related Object" and point it to the text that we want to identify, but there isn't a way to parameterize the text that we want to use as the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch to other identificatio methods like descriptor or xpath? You could try switch the method to descriptor in the click step and then add relative test object.

Does the webpage is public accessbile? If so please provide the link to help identify your request more precisely.

Comment: Webpage is not public accessible. As i said in list of all tasks every task has its unique id and we will pass id as parameter.

Comment: @Raghavi Is it possible to save parts of the DOM tree and paste it into the question? Here is another question may help you resolve this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818970/click-on-a-link-beside-text-in-truclient/60827721?noredirect=1#comment107636147_60827721